# How to include blank but disable it for simple form collection select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

So I need (for UX reasons) to include a blank field in select field (with include_blank: option), but disable it.
Is this possible to do?

I've been trying to pass

```
disabled: [nil]
```

and

```
disabled: [""]
```

But it does not seem to cut it..

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. However you could use a combination of `prompt`/`include_blank` and `required` to ensure the end-user selects a proper value:

```
<%= select_tag('foo', options_for_select([['bar','bar'],['baz','baz']]), prompt: "Select a Foo", required: true %>
```

or

```
<%= select_tag('foo', options_for_select([['bar','bar'],['baz','baz']]), required: true %>
```

`include_blank` is automatically set to `true` when you set the `required` option to `true` and no `prompt` is present.

Answer (score 1):

I am having a similar issue with filtering users by accepted insurance plans and cannot make the selection required (if none selected, show all users), so I added something like this to the controller (maybe hacky, but ensures a blank default first option that will be ignored unless the user selects another):

```rb
User.joins(:insurances).where(insurances: { id: query[:insurance] }) unless query[:insurance].first.empty?
```

where `query[:insurance]` returns `[""]` if none selected.